# Sum the product of the number of times a string occurs by cell value in loop

Tags: vba, loops, variables, if-statement

I'm new to VBA and I've been stuck with this for a while.

What I'm trying to do is to multiply the value in column A by the number of times a string occurs in each row. ie: a, b and c (in range B:D). Then sum that result with next row's result only if they share the same value in column E.

The number of times the a value is repeated in column E will vary from 1 to 30.

This is what I have so far

```
Sub MYSUB()
Dim ws_1 As Worksheet
Set ws_1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim b1 As Long, b2 As Long, b3 As Long
Dim j As Long
lr = ws_1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For r = 2 To lr

datei = ws_1.Cells(r, 5)
dayi = Day(datei)
a = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("t_tb"), "=" & CDbl(datei)) '''

For x = 1 To 3
If dayi = x Then

myrng = "B" & r & ":D" & r

b1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(myrng), "=" & "a")
b2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(myrng), "=" & "b")
b3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(myrng), "=" & "c")

If b1 > 0 Then ws_1.Cells(x + 1, 8) = b1 * ws_1.Cells(r, 1)
If b2 > 0 Then ws_1.Cells(x + 1, 9) = b2 * ws_1.Cells(r, 1)
If b3 > 0 Then ws_1.Cells(x + 1, 10) = b3 * ws_1.Cells(r, 1)

End If
If dayi = x Then GoTo NxtR
Next x

NxtR:
Next r

End Sub
```

[image: expl]

Comment: Good post. What would also help is if you included data using a [table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) and then post that between code tags so people can easily copy your data and use.

Comment: a appears 6 times in range B:D not 3...it does appear 3 times in range B, have I missed something or is part of the question in need or re-wording given your shown expected output? Do you mean for the same E column value to apply to the count as well?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. What I meant is to get the product of the number of times a string occurs (a,b or c) in "each row" (I think I missed that) then multiply it by the value in column A. Then IF the next row has the same value (date) in column E as the last row, sum the result in the last row (for a would be 3*1=3) with the result in the new one (for a, 2*2(two a's in range B3:D3) since they have the same date in column E. Sum 3+4 =7. Thing is the number of times a date in column E is repeated will vary, it could be 1 or it could be 10 or 30.

Comment: [edit] that info into your question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edited** to add a (much faster) `Dictionary` approach

you could use `AutoFilter()`

```
Sub MYSUB()
    Dim dataRng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim iCol As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set dataRng = .Range("E1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        With dataRng.Columns(5).Rows("2:" & dataRng.Rows.Count)
            .Offset(, 2).Value = .Value
            With .Offset(, 2)
                .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), header:=xlNo
                For Each cell In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    dataRng.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=" & cell.Value
                    For iCol = 1 To .Offset(-1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column - .Column ' be sure you have already filled cells H1 rightwards
                        cell.Offset(, iCol).Value = GetFilteredSum(dataRng, cell.Value, .Parent.Cells(1, cell.Column + iCol))
                    Next
                Next
            End With
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Function GetFilteredSum(rng As Range, myDate As Date, myVal As String) As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    With rng
        For iCol = 2 To 4
            .AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:=myVal
             GetFilteredSum = GetFilteredSum + Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, .Columns(1))
            .AutoFilter Field:=iCol 
        Next
    End With
End Function
```

or you could use `Dictionary` object, which is much much faster:

```
Sub MYSUB2()
    Dim data As Variant, key As Variant, key2 As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        data = .Range("E2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value
    End With

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For i = 1 To UBound(data)
            If Not .Exists(data(i, 5)) Then Set .Item(data(i, 5)) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            For j = 2 To 4
                If Not IsEmpty(data(i, j)) Then .Item(data(i, 5)).Item(data(i, j)) = .Item(data(i, 5)).Item(data(i, j)) + data(i, 1)
            Next
        Next

        i = 1
        For Each key In .Keys
            i = i + 1
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7) = Day(key)
            For Each key2 In .Item(key).Keys
                data = Application.Match(key2, Sheets("Sheet0001").Rows(1), 0)
                If Not IsError(data) Then Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, data) = .Item(key).Item(key2)
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Lol. I was using the similar approach but not as neat and was still typing. Nice.

Comment: @QHarr, I tested it with the very same OP's data with no issues

Comment: Sorry. You warning about H1 i totally ignored, or rather my eyes read H2 for no apparent reason!

Comment: QHarr, I mean, I assumed 1) there are no dates in column G (they are filled by the macro as unique dates from column E)  2) there are values to count for ("a", "b", "c") in cells H1 to J1

Comment: Plus 1. Very quick solution.